# Need a button that take me to a Editpage for a specific ID

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

Im building a MVC-application and one of the pages is updated with javascript. Need help figuring out how to link me to a specifik url with a HTML button.

Ill show you what i mean:

Im trying to do like i did here with the java value:

```
<img src="{2}" alt="blog image"/>
```

But it dont work here

```
"<input EntryId={0} type="button" value="Edit" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("UpdateEntry/{*IDFROMJAVASCRIPTHERE*}","Competition")'" />
```

Pretty sure i cant use the @Url.Action with java values. Whats the simplest way to solve this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MVC + Razor, you can do:

`@Html.ActionLink("Edit Me", "UpdateEntry", "Competition", new { id = item.ID }, new{ @class="button" });`